# malloc inside function causing SIGSEV

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am trying to write a generic queue implementation in C. For the initialization part, this is what I have:

```
struct queue{
  int head;
  int tail;
  int max_size;
  int elem_size;
  void **elements;
};

void queue_init(struct queue** q, int max_size, int elem_size){
  *q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  (*q)->head = (*q)->tail =0;
  (*q)->max_size = max_size;
  (*q)->elem_size = elem_size;
  (*q)->elements = malloc(max_size * elem_size);
}
```

To test the implementation, I wrote the following:

```
void klein_test(void){
  struct queue** qp;
  queue_init(qp, 1, 1);
  return;
}

int main(){
  klein_test();
}
```

While trying to run such test, I got a `SIGSEV`. Inspecting the execution with `gdb`, I could see that the error signal was being generated at `queue_init` 's first call to `malloc`. What is the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: The pointer struct queue** qp; is not initialized.

Comment: 'queue_init(qp, 1, 1);' qp is not initialized at that point.

Comment: To load that local, (which should probably be of 'queue*' type, you would need to pass it by address: 'queue_init(&qp, 1, 1);'.

Comment: To *emulate* pass-by-reference in C, you pass a pointer *to a variable* to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least write

```
struct queue* qp;
queue_init(&qp, 1, 1);
```

Also it is not clear why there is declaration

```
void **elements;
```

instead of just

```
void *elements;
```

Comment: I needed to use debugger for the same conclusion :)

Comment: Maybe because `elements` must be `elem_size` arrays of `max_size` items. BTW better to use contiguous memory with single pointer ;)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, You're absolutely right on both comments. Just waiting for SO to allow the answer acceptance. Thanks!

Comment: @LPs It is difficult to understand what is required. I understand this as an array of max_size elements of size elem_size.